# The Variable value updated in robotframework is not able to access afterwards

Tags: robotframework

I have declared a variable in `Variables` section and initiated as `${Empty}`.
Assigned the value in the TestCase and accessing the same in other keyword, it showed as ${Empty}.

my sample code is as below:

```
*** Variables ***
${fields}         ${Empty}

*** Test Cases ***
Sample Code
     ${fields}=   Get Service Details
     Validate Service Details

*** Keywords ***
Get Service Details
         ... code for Get Service Details
         [Return]  ${fields} 

Validate Service Details
      ${sValue}=     Get Text    ${serviceXpath}
      Should be Equal As Strings    ${fields}    ${sValue}
```

Here, my question is, i delcared ${fields} in `Variable` section, i assigned value comes from the keyword `Get Service Details`, i want to use the updated value in `Validate Service Details` section.

I thought, as i have declared the variable in `variable` section, the updated value will be there in `Validate Service Details` keyword, but it displayed empty value.

How I can get updated value in `Validate Service Details` keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Get Service Details`, call [Set Test Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Variable), [Set Suite Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable), or [Set Global Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Global%20Variable) instead of (or in addition to) using `[return]` to make the changes visible outside of the keyword scope.

```
*** Keywords ***
Get Service Details
    ... code for Get Service Details
    set test variable    ${fields}
```

Comment: Is automatically it will not update the variable without using `set test variable`